# VALUE error when attempting to format a date and time cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this date which is formatted as follows:
2020-11-30T17:52:06

To get it into the following format:
30/11/2020 17:52

I use the following formula:
=MID(N2,9,2)&"/"&MID(N2,6,2)&"/"&MID(N2,1,4)&" "&MID(N2,12,5)

However, the result is completely useless to me because I cant do anything with it.If I try to subtract the two times to get the difference I get a #VALUE! error. Even attempting to format it with a date is ignored. It stubbornly remains impervious to all formatting attempts. How do I get this to a datetime format that I can use?

Comment: It sounds like the cell is not text but actually a date. Press CTRL + 1, what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula creates a string rather than a true date.  Try:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,6,2),MID(A1,9,2))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))
```

and apply the proper format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," ")
```

[image]

Comment: what double negation is doing here?